# How to view web pages at different resolutions

Tags: internet-explorer, resolution

I am developing a web site and need to see how it will look at different resolutions. The catch is that it must work on our Intranet.

Is there a free solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Internet Explorer there's the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359). It lets you select resolutions quite easily.

Answer (score 8):

For Firefox, Web Developer Toolbar (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)

Answer (score 3):

Type in the address bar of your favorite browser:  javascript:resizeTo(1024,768)

Then adjust to your desired resolution. You can even save these as bookmarklets in your favorites/bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work if you are limited to test internally but [Browsercam](http://www.browsercam.com/) is a fantastic service when you want to check how well your website performs on various OS/browser combinations. It takes the guesswork out of browsertesting.

If you must stay within yout internal network then why don't you setup a virtual PC with the software you need? It's very easy to maintan a few sets of virtual PCs and simply boot the ones you need to test with. And of course you can test with various add-ons etc. using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I use a product called [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/). Technically, it's a product that allows you to have an easier management of your multiple monitor's. The cool thing (and what is important to this question) is that you can set up multiple "Display Profile's". I have two set up:

1. My default 1280*1024 on both monitors
2. One monitor at 1280*1024 and the other at 1024*768

It allows you to setup as many profiles as you want and I just switch between them to check different resolutions.

Answer (score -1):

Also on Internet Explorer 7 is [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/). It also provides some gadgets that aren't in the Developer Toolbar. I have both installed, and use both quite often.